# Snowflake - how do I retrieve the name of the currently executing procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to access the name of the currently executing procedure in Snowflake in the javascript procedure itself and store it in a variable.

When I interrogate the "this" object, I can see the name in the Variant return, but in terms of JSON I believe it's the name not the value and I'm not sure how to retrieve the first name in the JSON object.

**What code do I need to use to get the procedure name?**
procName = ???what code goes here with the this object???;

**Do we know that the first name/value pair in "this" will always be the procedure name?**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EDW_ADMIN.DAG_TEST()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS 
$$
var procName = "";
// procName = this.??? WHAT DO I PUT HERE ???
return this;
$$
;
```

The return / contents of "this" are:

```
{
  "DAG_TEST": {},
  "ResultSet": {},
  "SfTimestamp": {},
  "Snowflake": {},
  "Statement": {},
  "Status": {
    "EOF": "eof",
    "ERROR": "error",
    "INITIALIZED": "initialized",
    "SUCCESS": "success"
  },
  "_c_snowflake": {
    "createExecError": {},
    "createStatement": {}
  },
  "createError": {},
  "extractValue": {},
  "getColSqlTypeFromIdx": {},
  "nativeTypes": {
    "values": {
      "BOOLEAN": "boolean",
      "BUFFER": "buffer",
      "DATE": "date",
      "INVALID": "invalid",
      "JSON": "json",
      "NUMBER": "number",
      "STRING": "string"
    }
  },
  "noSuchColumnIdxErrorMessage": "Given column name/index does not exist: ",
  "snowflake": {
    "createStatement": {},
    "execute": {}
  },
  "sqlTypeFromLibSfDbTypeVal": {},
  "sqlTypes": {
    "isArray": {},
    "isBinary": {},
    "isBoolean": {},
    "isDate": {},
    "isNumber": {},
    "isObject": {},
    "isText": {},
    "isTime": {},
    "isTimestamp": {},
    "isTimestampLtz": {},
    "isTimestampNtz": {},
    "isTimestampTz": {},
    "isVariant": {},
    "values": {
      "ARRAY": {
        "libSfDbType": 9,
        "name": "ARRAY"
      },
      "BINARY": {
        "libSfDbType": 10,
        "name": "BINARY"
      },
      "BOOLEAN": {
        "libSfDbType": 12,
        "name": "BOOLEAN"
      },
      "DATE": {
        "libSfDbType": 3,
        "name": "DATE"
      },
      "FIXED": {
        "libSfDbType": 0,
        "name": "FIXED"
      },
      "INVALID_SQL_TYPE": {
        "libSfDbType": -1,
        "name": "INVALID_SQL_TYPE"
      },
      "OBJECT": {
        "libSfDbType": 8,
        "name": "OBJECT"
      },
      "REAL": {
        "libSfDbType": 1,
        "name": "REAL"
      },
      "TEXT": {
        "libSfDbType": 2,
        "name": "TEXT"
      },
      "TIME": {
        "libSfDbType": 11,
        "name": "TIME"
      },
      "TIMESTAMP_LTZ": {
        "libSfDbType": 4,
        "name": "TIMESTAMP_LTZ"
      },
      "TIMESTAMP_NTZ": {
        "libSfDbType": 5,
        "name": "TIMESTAMP_NTZ"
      },
      "TIMESTAMP_TZ": {
        "libSfDbType": 6,
        "name": "TIMESTAMP_TZ"
      },
      "VARIANT": {
        "libSfDbType": 7,
        "name": "VARIANT"
      }
    }
  },
  "testFunc": {},
  "typeFromLibSfDbTypeVal": {},
  "validateBinds": {},
  "validateColumnExists": {}
}
```

Comment: You can't pass the name of the proc in as a param? If you're not calling the stored proc dynamically then this should be pretty solid approach.

Comment: The procedure name is going to be used by a logging procedure such that a log table has a bunch of entries for different procedures.  I want it to be fool proof, and if you pass in the name of the proc when calling it or hard code it as a constant at the top of the proc it's prone to developer error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your proc:

```
const procName = Object.keys(this)[0];
```

Assuming that the procName is always the first key in the dictionary!  Also using const wherever possible is a good practice.

Comment: The stored proc name was the first key for me too. This approach is decent but does put you at risk if Snowflake decides to change the "this" object even slightly :(

Comment: True - I'll submit a ticket to them to make sure they are going to keep that locked down before I go to production.  Thanks for the answer, it's perfect, and thanks for the coaching on the use of "const" - great stuff!

Comment: It's a little risky to assume anything about the order of attributes in a dictionary.  As a coincidence the procedure name comes out first in a text sort.  Try renaming your procedure to `X_DAG_TEST` (capital `X`) and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Try CURRENT_STATEMENT(); haven't tested, so let us know