# How to get name of executing stored procedure in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does snowflake have function which returns name of the current stored procedure like the following in SQL Server.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
```

I am just trying to build a logging table to log all statements that are executed inside a stored procedure this is for monitoring purpose i.e. which statement within stored procedure failed and how long queries are taking to run. If Snowflake has something out-of-box OR a recommended way of doing it please share.

Answer (score 2):

Try this from within your stored procedure:

```
const procName = Object.keys(this)[0];
```

Also see this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296207/snowflake-how-do-i-retrieve-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-procedure/59310013#59310013).